# Extract part of string in R dataframe column

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr

I am trying to extact an ID thats a part of a string within a column in R. I would like to write an expression that would extract the art starting with IAB and ending in a number. how would I do this?

sample strings:

```
[31] "{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB1_4\"\"}"  
[32] "{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB19_3\"\"}" 
[33] "{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB19_16\"\"}"
[34] "{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB9_11\"\"}" 
[35] "{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB19_5\"\"}" 
[36] "{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB18_1\"\"}"
```

I need to extract just the part that starts with IAB and end in a number. How could I do this?

Comment: Looks like JSON strings nearly. If you're dealing with data like this it may be worth taking a look at the *jsonlite* package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` to match one or more digits (`\\d+`) after the string 'IAB' followed by an underscore (`_`) and one or more digits (`\\d+`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(v1, 'IAB\\d+_\\d+')
#[1] "IAB1_4"   "IAB19_3"  "IAB19_16" "IAB9_11"  "IAB19_5"  "IAB18_1"
```

---

Or with `regexpr` from `base R`

```
regmatches(v1, regexpr('IAB\\d+_\\d+', v1))
#[1] "IAB1_4"   "IAB19_3"  "IAB19_16" "IAB9_11"  "IAB19_5"  "IAB18_1"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB1_4\"\"}", "{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB19_3\"\"}", 
"{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB19_16\"\"}", "{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB9_11\"\"}", 
"{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB19_5\"\"}", "{\"\"element\"\":\"\"IAB18_1\"\"}"
)
```